# Ubuntu 15.04 - Chrome launcher icon

Tags: unity, 15.04, launcher, google-chrome, icons

I have a Chrome icon on the launcher, for about 3 months it worked "fine", i mean, starting the application highlighted the icon.

Lately happens when I start Chrome that a new Chrome window is added to the launcher.

I tried to unlock the "old" Chrome icon and to lock the new one, but it didn't solve my problem.

Does someone had similar problems?
Can anyone give me some advice?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Nautilus and press Ctrl + H.

Then go to `~/.local/share/applications` and remove all Chrome `.desktop` files.

Comment: Thank you! it did solve my problem, even if i had to do it many times..
At the beginning the Chrome icon was replaced by an "?" icon that if locked wouldn't start chrome after closing it..
after a couple of tries Chrome icon returned, i locket it and everything is fine now